# WSDL Soap actions, method name

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have the following WSDL file uploaded to Windows Azure Webistes

http://pippogr.azurewebsites.net/ChurchGuideServices.svc?wsdl

Can you tell me what are the values for the Soap_ACtion MEthod name, namespace for the Method: GetMessage

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it with in binding tag.....

```
 <wsdl:operation name="GetMessage">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IChurchGuideServices/GetMessage" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

and Namespace:

```
xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"
```